# Vuetify.js 2 - Data tables footer does not display properly with babel-polyfill

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

I'm using Data tables in Vuetify.js 2.0.10. The footer does not display properly in IE11 as bellow.

[image]

I read this document.
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start#ie-11-safari-9-support

I installed babel-polyfill and @/babel/preset-env and then configured babel.config.js and vue.config.js like bellow.

package.json

```
{
"name": "table-test",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
...
"dependencies": {
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.10",
    "vuetify": "^2.0.10",
    ...
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.5.5",
    ...
}
}
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
presets: [
    '@vue/app',
    '@babel/preset-env'
]
}
```

vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    transpileDependencies: ["vuetify"]
}
```

main.js

```
import "babel-polyfill";  // polyfill
import Vue from "vue";
import App from "./App.vue";
import router from "./router";
import store from "./store";
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
router,
store,
vuetify,
render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Vue template

```
<template>
<v-data-table
        :headers="headers"
        :items="desserts"
        class="elevation-1"
></v-data-table>

</template>
<script>
export default {
data: () => ({
    headers: [
        ...
    ],
    desserts: [
        ...
    ]
}),
};
</script>
```

My question is:
1. Is there any way to resolve this problem?
2. When I open this Vuetify document page in IE11
https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/data-tables
the footer displays properly, Why?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the following styles as a workaround. Maybe you need to adjust the pixel sizes to your own needs.

```css
// IE11 Data table footer fix
.v-data-footer__select {
  flex-basis: auto;

  .v-select {
    flex-basis: 50px;

    .v-select__selections {
      flex-basis: auto;
    }
  }
}

.v-list-item__content {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-width: 40px;
}
```